# C# Não foi possível encontrar o IMetadataExchange

Tags: c#, wcf

estou com o seguinte problema, ao criar um serviço WCF diz que o IMetadataExchange não foi encontrado, o meu APP.config é:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceHostWindows.GetService" >
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/getservice" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceHostWindows.IGetService">
    </endpoint>
   <endpoint name="MyServiceMex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
  </service> 
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name = "MyBeh">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Eu vi um comentário pedindo para adicionar  mas não resolveu o problema, o que devo fazer?

Comment: remova a linha que define o endpoint com `name="MyServiceMex"`

Comment: Então se eu remover o nome name="MyServiceMex" me aparece a seguinte mensagem "WCF Service Host cannot find any service metada. This may cause the client application to run improperly. Please check if metadata is enabled. Do you want to exit?" Se clico em SIM ele fecha se clico em NÃO ele abre, só que quando eu instalar o serviço e tentar iniciar o mesmo para dizendo que não tem nenhum processo usando ou senha o serviço não funciona, na verdade não sei se este problema com os meta dados que estão parando o serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei, tem que adicionar o  eu encontrei nessa resposta aqui mesmo no forum: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393767/wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-metadata-please-check-if-metadata-is-e][1]